# Forcefully return the 2 values when accessing map amid returning from function

Tags: go

I know a map is accessible like this:

```
value := someMap["someKey"]
```

To check if a key exists in a map, I can use this:

```
value, exists := someMap["someKey"]
if exists {
    fmt.Printf("has value: %s", value)
}
```

Regarding 2nd code however, it doesn't work in this case:

```
var bag = make(map[string]interface{}, 0)

var mux = sync.Mutex{}

// Retrieves data
func Get(key string) (interface{}, bool) {
    mux.Lock()
    defer mux.Unlock()

    return bag[key] // I receive "wrong number of return values (want 2, got 1)compiler"
}
```

How can I forcely return both values from accessing `bag` map amid returning from `Get` function? I use Go 1.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly say that you want the two values

```
// Retrieves data
func Get(key string) (interface{}, bool) {
    mux.Lock()
    defer mux.Unlock()

    v ,ok := bag[key]
    return v, ok 
}
```

Comment: I know it works. Though I want to know if there is a way to forcefully return value and key state directly, without assigning them to variables

Comment: @user8555937: No, there is not.